# How to read serialized data when serialVersionUID don't match?

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

I have data in an ArrayList written to a stream:

```
public class CustomHoliday implements Serializable {    
    String name;
    int day;
    int month;
}

ArrayList<CustomHoliday> allCustomHolidays;

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(allCustomHolidays);
```

When I try to read that with

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(filename);
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
allCustomHolidays = (ArrayList<CustomHoliday>) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

I get this Exception:

> java.io.InvalidClassException: CustomHoliday; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8822681925170234017, local class serialVersionUID = -8039319578138251384

Yes, I know, I should've declared a `serialVersionUID` in CustomHoliday. But now it's too late for that. I've tried to set the `serialVersionUID` to the one from the Exception, but that only does the trick on that device. In other instances the saved `serialVersionUID` seems to be different.

Even if I could read the `serialVersionUID` from the stream beforehand, I wouldn't be able to set it dynamically in CustomHoliday due to `serialVersionUID` being `final`.

Is there a way to tell Java: "Don't worry about the serialVersionUID, it'll be fine!"?

If not, is there another way I can read the data from the stream? It's just a String and two ints per CustomHoliday instance.

Comment: Just add a `serialVersionUID` member *now*, with the value shown as expected in the exception. But to get this outcome you must already have changed and recompiled the class between serialziing and deserializing, so the result may not be what you expect.

Comment: As I've already described, I tried to set the `serialVersionUID` to the one in the Exception. You assume right, although the class did not change, it has been recompiled since the data got serialized.

Comment: So you didn't do it right, or you didn't deploy the new .class file to the receiving side.

Comment: There is no 'receiving side'. Both the serialization and deserialization happens in the same class. The serialized data gets written to a private file and never leaves the device. This is all part of an Android App.